# как сделать такую форму

Tags: vue.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть форма с чекбоксами такого вида и есть данные для чекбоксов в таком виде
limitSchedule: "001111111111111111111111101111111111111111111111110111111111111111111111111011011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
вопрос как правильнее сверстать и заполнить эту форму, мне пока пришел в голову только один вариант, превратить строку в масив, разбить его на 7 объектов и их уже перербрать в компоненте

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что что он содержит несколько общих вопросов (без достаточной конкретизации проблемы), и задан картинкой (вместо текстового описания) - в таком виде, вопрос будет бесполезен для сообщества.

Comment: Вместо 7 объектов, в локальном состоянии компонента тут будет достаточно одного массива булевых значений (`dataString.split('').map(v => v === '1')`). Алгоритм сериализации значений формы для отправки серверу, напрямую не связан с организацией данных в состоянии UI, и целиком зависит от того что ожидает бэкэнд, но в вопросе об этом ни слова (и это уже _другой_ вопрос - который должен быть задан отдельно, если он интересует).